# Vim and snipMate (plugin) - adding new snippet won't work

Tags: vim, snipmate

I am trying to create a new snippet to my snipMate plugin.

I work with some files called (i.e.) myfile.endfile

All .endfile files should have the same "snippet" like .html files. 
So I did

```
cp html.snippet endfile.snippet
```

in my ~/.vim/snippets directory.

SnipMate is working with all present snippets, but not with my new created one.
Any suggestions for this problem?

(Btw: after creating the new .snippet file, I ran `:helptags ~/.vim/doc` command in an vim instance.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is because Snipmate works with `filetype`, which is a Vim option set when opening a file of a particular type.

For exemple, if you are opening, "index.html" the `filetype` is automatically set to `html`.

To see how it works, do :
`:e $VIMRUNTIME/filetype.vim`

As a preliminary test, you can :
1. open test.endfile
2. type `:set ft=endfile` or `:set filetype=endfile`
3. Check if your defined snippets now work

To do that automatically add the following in your .vimrc :
`au BufNewFile,BufRead *.endfile set filetype=endfile`

It means that every time you read or create a new file ending in `endfile`the filetype option is set to endfile.

(The filetype is an arbitrary string it doesn't have to be identical to the file extension)

Comment: Thank you! Now it is working! But now my highlighting ist gone. Is there a way to add this again? EDIT: au BufNewFile,BufRead *.endfile set filetype=html.endfile will fix the highlightning again.

Comment: If you had already syntax coloring, a filetype was probably already associated with your file. Can you remove the line I asked you to add in .vimrc, reopen your file and type `:set ft?`. It should display the current filetype of the file. All you have to do then, it is to rename your snippet file to the file type being already in use. And you should get both syntax coloring and snipmate working.

Answer (score 4):

You can assign snippets without altering the filetype (which is desirable, because altering the filetype breaks syntax highlighting).

I believe the proper way to do this in the [maintained fork of snipmate](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) is to set g:snipMate.scope_aliases.

In your example, assuming you have an 'endfile.snippet' file, I believe adding the following to your .vimrc would work:

```
let g:snipMate = {}
let g:snipMate.scope_aliases = {}
let g:snipMate.scope_aliases['html'] = 'endfile'
```

If you want both html and endfile snippets to work for files of filetype='html', then use:

```
let g:snipMate = {}
let g:snipMate.scope_aliases = {}
let g:snipMate.scope_aliases['html'] = 'html,endfile'
```

I've added a [pull request](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate/pull/77) to snipmate to have their documentation updated. **Edit:** It has now been merged.

Answer (score 0):

I found it convenient to use **global** snippets when using snippets that have uncommon name.endfile.

When you put your snippets in **_.snippets** file inside snippets folder they become global and are accessible in every filetype.

Maybe this is not directly answer to the question but a lot of users with similar problem can find this convenient. Specially if they don't have need to have everything organised in various files and are happy to have their own snippets in one file that is accessible everywhere.