# How can I enable SCSS snippets for Vim's SnipMate?

Tags: vim, sass, snipmate

I have installed [garbas’s snipMate fork](https://github.com/garbas/vim-snipmate) and [honza’s snippet repository](https://github.com/honza/snipmate-snippets) for Vim 7.3. I’m running OS X Lion 10.7.5.

I’m able to get everything working properly, as expected — my problem occurs when trying to add `scss.snippets` (I have tried to do so both as a plugin and manually into the snippets folder, with the same results). I know my new snippet file is recognized, because I tested it by adding CSS snippets to the newly-created `scss.snippets` file. I knew this would cause a collision, and it did in fact bring up the collision prompt (as [outlined in the snipmate docs](https://github.com/davidhalter/vim-snipmate/blob/master/doc/snipMate.txt)).

The specific problem: Typing a trigger and then <kbd>Tab</kbd> deletes the trigger and doesn’t return the expanded snippet.

I have tried setting the filetype and also the `scope.alias` solution proposed in [Vim and snipMate (plugin) - adding new snippet won't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488786/vim-and-snipmate-plugin-adding-new-snippet-wont-work) and in the docs, but I get the same results. Lastly, I tried eliminating all potential n00b mistakes by trying the above solutions against a clean `.vimrc` file. Again, I get the same results.

10 million virtual high-fives for anyone who can help me — until then, I’ll be bouncing my head off my desk awaiting my salvation... or perhaps reinstalling TextMate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your `scss` file correctly recognized as `scss` filetype? Is your config available online?

Comment: I was unsuccesfull with: au BufRead,BufNewFile *.scss set filetype=scss

Comment: .vimrc here: https://gist.github.com/4533079

Comment: That autocmd should work.

Comment: update: read somewhere that :set paste! within .vimrc can cause troubles with snipmate. disabled, but got same results.

Comment: i also experienced the problem before. It seems like the scss.snippets  that i've downloaded are not indented correctly since they are all highlighted in an Error hightlight when i view it in vim.

what i did was just reindent the source code until all the Error highlights disappeared. 

then i edited some scss files and the scss snippets worked.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the snippets you used are not indented correctly or there's some mistakes in the syntax of those snippets which Snipmate then fails to autocomplete
Try looking at that particular snippets file and see if it's highlighted in some way.

it's just probably a wrong indentation of the source code.

Because i *reproduced* the problem on my scss.snippets file by reindenting or using improper syntax on the snippet files.

**NOTE:** the snippets use **tabs** instead of **spaces** so be sure to disable expandtab

```
:set noet or :set noexpandtab
```

I myself, don't know the reason behind this.